# How can I change digclock signals from analog to digital?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, clock, pspice

I want to get a digital singl from dstm 1,2,3,4.
but it didn't work.

[image]

runing time is 8.5ms

The simulation results from analog are similar to the results that you want to see as digital signals.
[image]
But, I want to get more accurate value.

What's the problem?

I want to get digital input!!!!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  You are adding four digital signals with different gain values for each.  The output looks reasonable.  Where do you want more accuracy?  If anything your signal is losing the final signal peaks due to the op amp limitations,  (The 741 op amp is not rail to rail type, choose another op amp for better output).  You could also increase the supply voltages, or reduce the overall gain to prevent the loss of the peak output level.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: The title says that you want to convert analog to digital, but the circuit presented is a digital to analog converter. You need to explain your problem more completely and in more detail.